# Convert string to integer and display it in momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert this value that i have to number so i can manipulate it.
I am using the format method in moment.js.

```
      var startTime = moment("06:51 am", "HH:mm a");

      document.getElementById("start").textContent =  'Start = ' +startTime.format('HH:mm a');
```

**the result now is 66**

i am trying to make the value in startTime  number(int) so i can sum it with another number

**expected result : 12**

**the full JS code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var startTime = moment("06:51 am", "HH:mm a");

  var endTime = moment("04:16 pm", "HH:mm a");
  var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
  var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
  var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;

  document.getElementById("start").textContent =  'Start = ' +startTime.format('HH:mm a');
  document.getElementById("end").textContent = 'End = ' +endTime.format('h:mm a');
  document.getElementById("time").textContent = 'Difference ' +hours+ ' hour and '+ minutes+' minutes.' ;
}
```

**My failed attempt:**

```
  document.getElementById("pp").textContent =  'Start = ' +parseInt((startTime.format("H"))+6;
```

and thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

these issues are generally easy to solve. but you need to provide the exact error message for people to help you. saying 'failed' is not very helpful. I would suggest doing this:

```
console.log(startTime);
console.log(startTime.format("H"));
document.getElementById("pp").textContent =  'Start = ' +parseInt((startTime.format("H"))+6;
```

then tell us everything you see in the console for those 3 statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, you just need to put them between ()

```
  document.getElementById("pp").textContent =  'Start = ' +(parseInt(startTime.format("H"))+6);
```

Comment: right. the problem is you are trying to mix strings and numbers together on the same line using + operator for both. and in some cases you want it to act as string concatenation and other times as addition. the compiler has to try to figure out which one you meant and it's not always thinking the way you want it to.